# pymongo and output of aggregate

Tags: output, aggregate, pymongo

Here is my pymongo call

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['somedb']
collection = db.some_details
pipe = [{'$group': {'_id': '$mvid', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}]
TestOutput = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
print(list(TestOutput))
client.close()
```

For some reason resulting list is empty, while in Robomongo I get nonempty output.

Is formatting incorrect?

The exact Robomongo query is

```
db.some_details.aggregate([{$group: {_id: '$mvid', count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

**UPDATE**
The output looks like

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "4f973d56a64facfaa7c3r4rf262ad5be695eef329aff7ab4610ddedfb8137427",
            "count" : 84.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "a134106e1a1551d296fu777cedc933e7df2d0a9bc5f41de047aba3ee29bace78",
            "count" : 106.0000000000000000
        }, 

    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Comment: what is the result of  `db` in Robomongo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are again adding `db` to `collection` otherwise code seems to be OK to me.

Here is modified version of your code :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['somedb']
collection = db.some_details
pipe = [{'$group': {'_id': '$mvid', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}]
# Notice the below line
TestOutput = collection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
print(list(TestOutput))
client.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, Abhijeet. Dropping `db` did not help. Simpler queries such as `find` work without `db`, but `aggregate` is different. Plus official pymongo tutorial mentions `db` (http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html?highlight=aggregate). I guess I going to try to dump query output to json file and then read it into python.

Comment: Apologies, Abhijeet! Actually removing `db` helped. The returning object is some sort of collection of dictionaries. Casting it to `list` does not work, but one can iterate through this collection. I guess official pymongo tutorial is not very accurate.